# My Illustrator CC graphics appear pixelated and paths are jagged.

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, path, pixelation

I'm using Illustrator CC and my paths appear pixelated. I have no idea what may have caused the pixelation since it just started happening out of the blue. The image I've attached shows the saved jpg version of the image vs. the image displayed in Illustrator. Please help! [image]

Comment: Please see the duplicate link above your question. In addition, you may need to ensure **Anti-Alias Artwork** is **Checked** in the **Preferences**.